# Why "dispose()" and "setVisible()" isn't close the form?

Tags: java, swing, jframe, dispose

I got 2 forms from JFrame class. By button clicking, one of them must be closed and another opened. I've tried with "setVisible()" and "dispose()", results was the same - nothing didnt change. Below my code of classes with version with "dispose()"-try:

```
 public static void btnEnterHandler() throws Exception{
    JFrame mainFrame = Forms.mainFrameDraw(new Chat());
    JFrame enterFrame = Forms.enterFrameDraw(new Chat());
    try{
        enterFrame.dispose();
        mainFrame.setVisible(true);
    } catch(Exception ex2) {
        Logger.getLogger(enterFrame.getName());
    }
    //todo stopped here!
}
```

And class with forms:

```
public static JFrame mainFrameDraw(JFrame frame) {
    textAreaMain = new JTextArea(FRM_HEIGHT / 19, 50);
    textFieldMessage = new JTextField();
    textAreaMain.setLineWrap(true);
    textAreaMain.setEditable(false);
    JScrollPane spMain = new JScrollPane(textAreaMain);
    spMain.setLocation(0, 0);

    JButton btnSend = new JButton();
    btnSend.setText("Send");
    btnSend.setToolTipText("Broadcast a message");
    btnSend.addActionListener(e -> {
        try {
            Chat.btnSendHandler();
        } catch (Exception e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
    });

    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setTitle(FRM_TITLE);
    frame.setLocation(FRM_LOC_X, FRM_LOC_Y);
    frame.setSize(FRM_WIDTH, FRM_HEIGHT);
    frame.setResizable(false);
    frame.getContentPane().add(BorderLayout.NORTH, spMain);
    frame.getContentPane().add(BorderLayout.CENTER, textFieldMessage);
    frame.getContentPane().add(BorderLayout.EAST, btnSend);
    frame.setVisible(false);

    return frame;
}

public static JFrame enterFrameDraw(JFrame frame){
    JButton btnEnter = new JButton("Sign in!");
    textFieldLogin = new JTextField("Login!");
    btnEnter.addActionListener(e -> {
        try{
            Chat.btnEnterHandler();
        } catch (Exception e2){
            e2.printStackTrace();
        }
    });


    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setTitle(FRM_TITLE);
    frame.setLocation(FRM_LOC_X, FRM_LOC_Y);
    frame.setSize(FRM_WIDTH, FRM_HEIGHT);
    frame.getContentPane().add(BorderLayout.PAGE_START, textFieldLogin);
    frame.setResizable(false);
    frame.getContentPane().add(BorderLayout.PAGE_END, btnEnter);
    frame.setVisible(true);

    return frame;
}
```

}

It's not all code. But i think, it's enough. If you'll need more - give me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, try to avoid using only static classes because it's actually not what's java about. Get some knowledge about **SOLID principles**, it will help you out so much.

If it's about your case:

```
 JFrame mainFrame = Forms.mainFrameDraw(new Chat());
 JFrame enterFrame = Forms.enterFrameDraw(new Chat());
```

On button click it seems like you are initializing completely new frames, and then immediately close one of them:

```
enterFrame.dispose();
```

What you want to do is have instance of your `JFrame` inside `btnEnterHandler()`.

Working example (but still please consider not using so many static!):

```
public static JFrame enterFrameDraw(JFrame frame){
    //...
    btnEnter.addActionListener(e -> {
        try{
            Chat.btnEnterHandler(frame);
        } catch (Exception e2){
            e2.printStackTrace();
        }
    });
```

Then your handler looks like:

```
public static void btnEnterHandler(JFrame frame) throws Exception{
    JFrame mainFrame = Forms.mainFrameDraw(new Chat());
    try{
        frame.dispose();
        mainFrame.setVisible(true); //i'm pretty sure its not necessary because its visible by default
    } catch(Exception ex2) {
        Logger.getLogger(enterFrame.getName());
    }
}
```